# CMakeList.txt ${log-lib} not found

Tags: cmake

I am developing an android app. Since we use 'C++' on the backend, we want to use the 'log-lib' library to output the 'log'. But I get NOTFOUND error.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

add_library( score_printer

             # Sets the library as a shared library.
             SHARED

             # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
             src/main/main.cpp
            )


find_library( log-lib
              log )

target_link_libraries( score_printer
                       android
                       log
                      # Links the target library to the log library
                      # included in the NDK.
                      ${log-lib}
                      )
```

**ERROR MESSAGE**

```
C/C++ debug|armeabi-v7a : CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
  Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
  log-lib
      linked by target "score_printer" in directory project_dir
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use an old version of cmake. For me, 3.27.4 didn't work and 3.18.4 works perfectly.

In my opinion, the reason of that error is that the version of cmake doesn't fit the version of ndk. So changing either the version of cmake or the version of ndk will do the magic.